# Install OBS on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS Codename: bionic

Tags: apt, software-installation, ppa

Followed instructions at https://obsproject.com/wiki/install-instructions#ubuntu-installation for Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg << installed ok
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio << installed ok
```

```
sudo apt-get update
```

> ```
> http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu bionic InRelease
> ```

```
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

> obsproject-ubuntu-obs-studio-bionic.list

```
obsproject-ubuntu-obs-studio-bionic.list
```

> deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu bionic main
>
> '#deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu bionic main'

```
When I try `sudo apt-get install obs-studio`
```

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> E: Unable to locate package obs-studio

```
apt-cache policy obs-studio
```

> N: Unable to locate package obs-studio

Any advice ?

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy obs-studio` to the question by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1196411/edit) it.